# AWS \hooks\appdeploy\enact hook does not finish

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I currently have

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PATH=%PATH%;
powershell -nologo -noprofile -command "ps PriceStreamerConsole -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | kill -PassThru -Force"
RD /S /Q C:\inetpub\wwwroot;
MD C:\inetpub\wwwroot;
powershell -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('c:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle.zip', 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'); }"
cd "C:\inetpub\wwwroot"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /verbosity:quiet /t:"PriceStreamerConsole:Rebuild"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /verbosity:quiet /t:"PriceStreamerConsole:Rebuild" PriceStreamerConsole.sln
START "" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PriceStreamerConsole\bin\Debug\PriceStreamerConsole.exe"
```

When I deploy from local using "eb deploy", I get:

```
Creating application version archive "app-f28f-160721_124638".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         

ERROR: Timed out while waiting for command to Complete. The timeout can be set using the --timeout option.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using option settings. Option settings can be specified using ebextensions.

Create a file in your app source in a directory called `.ebextensions`. Lets say the file is `.ebextensions/01-increase-timeout.config`.

The contents of the file should be:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 1000
```

Note this file is in YAML format.
After this you can update your environment with this version of source code.